# jasmine 2 integration test

Tags: jquery, ajax, jasmine

I am trying to test a real ajax request with jasmine 2.3.4 but I don't know how to handle the ajax call. My code is something like

```
describe("testing user-info calls", function() {
  it("should make a real AJAX request", function () {
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy();            
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/userinfo/username",
            async: false,
            success: callback
    });
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Antonio');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [asynchronous documentation](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support), it should do what you're after.

```
describe("testing user-info calls", function() {
  it("should make a real AJAX request", function (done) {
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/userinfo/username",
            async: false,
            success: function(arg) {
              expect(arg).toEqual('Antonio');
              done();
            });
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need to hit the server, you could use sinon.js to use a fakeServer:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
});

afterEach(function () {
  server.restore();
});

describe("testing user-info calls", function() {
  it("should make a real AJAX request", function () {
    server.respondWith("GET", "data/userinfo/username",
                       [200, { "Content-Type": "text" },
                        'Antonio']);
    var callback = jasmine.createSpy();            
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "data/userinfo/username",
            async: false,
            success: callback
    });
    server.respond();
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Antonio');
  });
});
```

Comment: I got this error with your code
    "Expected spy unknown to have been called with [ 'Antonio' ] but it was   never called."

Comment: Which set of code? I've edited the first bit to change the test a little, and the second one you'll need to include sinon.js in your spec runner. Here's a JS Bin https://jsbin.com/tixewa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi Lee, many thanks for your reply.
When I run your first code block I got this error
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
I am running that code in a single page app built upon kendo ui  and spring rest services. I even tried to insert the ajax call in the before each block but still not working :-|

Comment: Hmm, you can increase the timeout by adding `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 20000;` in a `beforeEach` block, where `20000` is time in ms. How long is the endpoint taking to respond?

Comment: 13 ms on the network tab.
But I have everything in local

Comment: How do you mean local, are running a local server or from file://? It should work. Have you put a breakpoint on your controller action to make sure the server is recieving the request during your test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94209/discussion-between-antonio-and-lee).